# Review button highlights even if the user is banned

Tags: discussion

I recently got punished for making two wrong reviews on Stack Overflow for **Triage** queue, and I was asked to come back in 2 days to start review again.

But, in an hour, or so, the queue list button highlights, and when I click on it, there is nothing to do. Refer to below snapshot:

[image]

Just wanted to know if this is a bug, or is it an expected thing to happen?

Comment: The topbar notifications for reviews are not personalized for performance reasons. When you click the icon they actually query what is available for you. In this case that is none.